# What do I do about the "haziness when booting up Ubuntu?"

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, the Windows Installer method, and when I restarted and booted up Ubuntu, it was static and hazy. I rebooted back to Windows 7. 
I did like Ubuntu for about two minutes, but that haziness was just too much, and I could barely read anything.

I researched the problem, and people said it could be the graphics card I have. I am not tech savvy when it comes to computers, so I have no idea how to find out my graphics card model number or even change it. I have an HP Pavilion Dv2000 laptop with Windows 7 installed. Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's hardware than you need to order a new graphics card, find the exact make and model of your laptop for this, you can do it on a terminal, or a google search, or on the laptop itself on the sticker on the bottom. Than find the exact card you need. If you feel you can't do it yourself i'd suggest bringing it to someone who does that for a living :P

Comment: thank you. But sadly, i don't know  if it is a hardware issue. I just went back to Ubuntu and it is still hazy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experimenting with the driver for graphic card but it's worth the risk. Sometime it will work but sometimes it might not work. Worst you could see just blackout or reinstalling Ubuntu. If success, all your graphic card features will be available.

Try install other version of graphic card driver from the **System Settings > Software and Updates**.

[image]

Hope it help.